# Image Uploading with Classic ASP

Tags: image, asp-classic, upload, components

Hey I was wondering if there were any way to upload images in ASP?  I am working on my school's server and I don't really know what is installed and what isn't I Googled a little and came up with "Persits.Upload.1"  I tried to instantiate the object with this line:

`Set Upload = Server.CreateObject("Persits.Upload.1")`

It gave me this error,

> Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3'
>   Server.CreateObject Failed

Am I to assume the component is not installed on the server and/or what should I do for uploading images?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like it couldn't load the class, my ASP very rusty though.

That component is a commercial one, so unless someone has paid for it, you probably don't have it installed.

I have used free asp upload http://www.freeaspupload.net/ a few times, although it was a while a go, that might be a reasonably easy option for you.

Answer (score 2):

File upload is a built in part of html and you can process it in asp without any custom compents.  Here is some more information:
https://web.archive.org/web/20180312071127/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com:80/webtech/LearnMore/Upload.asp

Answer (score 1):

This is part of the ASPJpeg library, which needs to be purchased (From Persits.com).

I have used this library to upload multiple items in the past.

To upload a single file you can use the `<INPUT type=file name=filename>`.  This is just HTML though, but should work in all browsers

Answer (score 0):

If it's for educational purposes it may be worth droping [Persits](http://www.aspupload.com/support.html) an email to see if they will give you a free license.

They offer a 30-day free trial on their site.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Will Rickards' link is good.  You will also need permissions for the IUSR to create files in whatever directory you are uploading too.

IIS (6 I think?) comes with a limit of 200K for uploading files.  Only the server admin can change it to allow more.

If you can get your schools server to install COM objects, there are a number of free uploading tools that make things very easy.

Answer (score 0):

I have older classic ASP apps that use the Persits Software AspUpload component.  It works great if you need to resize images, get image dimensions, etc., during the upload process.
It is a component you need to purchase and it needs to be installed on the Web server in order for it to work.  It is not a core part of ASP.

Answer (score 0):

by the way, you have a typo in your code, is

```
Server.CreateObject("Persist.Upload.1")
```

and not

```
Server.CreateObject("Persits.Upload.1")
```

I bet that if you correct this, the code will go smooth :D

Comment: Although "persist" is a great word to describe an upload, the object is made by the company, "Persits Software, Inc."